# Communication from Firefox Extension to C# Application

Tags: c#, firefox, firefox-addon, builder, add-on

I need to send a string from my Firefox Extension to my C# application.

I use the add-on builder (https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/new).

Can i get some HelloWorld?

Comment: Have you seen this other post? [Communication from C# Application to Firefox Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561378/communication-from-c-sharp-application-to-firefox-extension?rq=1)

Comment: The compiler complains about this line:
    var fileStream = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);

"XPI not built"

Comment: I looked into it a bit and i think that the approach in that other link is intended for xul based extensions, not the addon-sdk like you are attempting. I think that error is related to that. I'm not sure how to do this kind of things in addon-sdk, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write to a file from your extension then read from it in your C#. 
To write the file in addon-sdk you can use [io/file](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.html)

There is a simple example in this post: [HTML5 File API in Firefox Addon SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12478363/1385896)