# Loading an audio file with the Add-On SDK and playing it with Aurora.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently trying to write a music player add-on for Mozilla Firefox using the Add-On SDK. I'm using [Aurora.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js) ([Wiki](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js/wiki)) to handle loading/demuxing/decoding the audio files

I've currently got the add-on working so you can select an audio file with an HTML file input, which is pretty straight forward.

```
    <input type="file" id="file-selector" />
    <script>
        var fileSelector = document.getElementById("file-selector");

        fileSelector.onchange = function() {
            var audioFile = fileSelector.files[0];

            var audioPlayer = AV.Player.fromFile(audioFile);

            audioPlayer.play();
        };
    </script>
```

What I'm currently trying to do though, is read a file returned from the add-on SDK rather than the file from the input on the HTML page, and create an AV.Player. Reading a file is simple enough using the [`sdk/io/file`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.html) and [`sdk/io/byte-streams`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/byte-streams.html) modules.

The problem is I can't figure out how to properly construct a AV.Player from this data. From what it looks like:

1. `AV.Player.fromFile(x)` works by constructing a `AV.Asset` from `AV.Asset.fromFile(x)`
2. `AV.Asset.fromFile(x)` constructs an `AV.Asset` with `AV.FileSource(x)`
3. `AV.FileSource` is constructed by creating a `FileReader` and 
   reading the data from the file as a Blob

I've been trying to figure out how to create a Blob with the byte array returned by io/file.read(filePath, "br") with no luck. I tried creating an object that resembles a Blob with size, type, and a slice method, but that also didn't seem to work.

Comment: Would love to see this when its done!

Comment: It actually shouldn't be too long before we release a primitive version, you can find the [github here](https://github.com/mozillamsu/). Our widgets will be targeting the Australis release of Firefox, you can find out a bit more about the project on [Jared Wein's blog](http://msujaws.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/student-project-australis-styled-widgets/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you will be (or at least should be) using Aurora in some content script (widget, panel, ...), things will be a little more complex.

1. Read data in your `main.js`, e.g. via the `file` module you already mentioned.
2. Pass that data over to the content script via messaging.
3. In the content script, receive the message, wrap the bytes in a `Uint8Array` and do your Aurora thing:

   ```
   addon.port.on("bytes-loaded", function(stream) {
     var data = new Uint8Array(stream.length);
     for (var i = 0; i < stream.length; ++i) {
         data[i] = String.charCodeAt(stream[i]) & 0xff;
     }
     avPlayer = AV.Player.fromBuffer(data);
   });
   ```

The `file` module isn't really good, as it is a synchronous API that will block while reading the file, but there is at least [one alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12478363/484441).

A complete example with `NetUtil` async file reading, and without the need to convert the string to an array in Javascript land can be found in [**this builder**](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/204161/latest/), but make sure to replace the hardcoded path. ;)

Comment: [Here's my Github repo](https://github.com/Schwig/australis-music-widget/tree/master/widget).

I've tried the code you posted before and it didn't work. I was hoping adding the {type: "audio/mpeg"} would help, but no dice. The script also freaks out if I try to call new Blob(data.bytes, ...) instead of new Blob([data.bytes], ...)

Whether I read the file in text mode or binary mode doesn't seem to make a difference either.

Comment: About the `Blob`: Yeah I always mess up the new call. The first argument of course should be an array. Corrected. About the rest: I'll have a look when I find some time.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was on the right track, but I wasn't converting to the Uint8Array properly. Also a big thanks for the asynchronous example, I wasn't aware of those modules :)